# Changing Windows 8 Toast Notification sound in app development

Tags: notifications, windows-8, microsoft-metro, toast, windows

I am developing windows 8 app for message delivery notification using toast in JavaScript and Html.
As by default toast sound is "Default" , But I want to convert it into "sms" sound.
I am also taking input from the user for, what to show during notification.

my HTML code looks like

```
<div>String to display <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20"      
id="inputString" /></div>
<button id="inputButton" class="action">button</button>
```

javascript code looks like

```
(function () {
"use strict";
var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/home.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        document.getElementById("inputButton").addEventListener("click", noti, false);
 ...


function noti(e) {
    var targetButton = e.currentTarget;
```

now I am stuck what to do now ..

I have following code from sample sdk , which I am unable to fit with

```
 var toastSoundSource = targetButton.id;

    // Get the toast manager for the current app.
    var notificationManager = Notifications.ToastNotificationManager;

    var content = ToastContent.ToastContentFactory.createToastText02();

    content.audio.content = ToastContent.ToastAudioContent[toastSoundSource];
```

I have also  read few blogs which says it can be done with just using it

```
toast.Audio.Content = ToastAudioContent.Silent;
```

I think I am just messing it up. kindly help soon.thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've being checking your code, and indeed your problem is here:

```
var toastSoundSource = targetButton.id; // you are getting the id of your button, however your button ID is not a valid index for the sounds we have available in Win8.
content.audio.content = ToastContent.ToastAudioContent[toastSoundSource]; //so when your code arrive here, nothing changes, and Winjs keeps using the DEFAULT sound...
```

In order to fix the problem you have... you can do 2 things, change the button id to "sms" or implement your code in one of the following ways:

1st - forcing windows to use SMS (if this is the only sound you want to use...

```
 function noti(e) {
    var targetButton = e.currentTarget;
    var toastSoundSource = targetButton.id;
    // Get the toast manager for the current app.
    var notificationManager = Notifications.ToastNotificationManager;
    var content = ToastContent.ToastContentFactory.createToastText02();
    content.audio.content = ToastContent.ToastAudioContent.sms; // force system to use SMS sound
    var toast = content.createNotification();
    notificationManager.createToastNotifier().show(toast);
}
```

2nd - you can create a if/else, if you have more options available, than code can choose on the sound based on the button clicked...

```
function noti(e) {
    var targetButton = e.currentTarget;
    var toastSoundSource = targetButton.id;
    // Get the toast manager for the current app.
    var notificationManager = Notifications.ToastNotificationManager;
    var content = ToastContent.ToastContentFactory.createToastText02();

    if ( toastSoundSource == "inputButton") 
       content.audio.content = ToastContent.ToastAudioContent.sms;
    else 
           content.audio.content = ToastContent.ToastAudioContent.im

    var toast = content.createNotification();
    notificationManager.createToastNotifier().show(toast);
}
```

I hope this helps :)